# Boto3 S3 list object throwing error in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Code in lambda:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
    mybucket = s3_client.Bucket('bucket-name')
    for object in mybucket.objects.all():
       print(object)

    for key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='bucket-name')['Contents']:
       print(key['Key'])'
```

the first 'for' block list all the keys in the bucket but the second 'for' block throws following error.

```
's3.Service Resource' object has no attribute 'list_objects' : AttributeError
```

It doesn't make sense based on http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets . any hint on what could be the problem? i used python 2.7 as well as python 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [boto3 service resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource) is not the same as the older boto library's service client. You are apparently mixing the documentation of the two.

A client is low level client, and just wraps the AWS APIs to python basic datatypes. All services have a client available in boto3.

Do check the documentation for [a Resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) and [a Client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html).

> ### Resources
>
> Resources represent an object-oriented interface to Amazon Web
>   Services (AWS). They provide a higher-level abstraction than the raw,
>   low-level calls made by service clients.
>
> ```
> resource = boto3.resource('s3')
> ```
>
> ### Clients
>
> Clients provide a low-level interface to AWS whose methods map close
>   to 1:1 with service APIs. All service operations are supported by
>   clients. Clients are generated from a JSON service definition file.
>
> ```
> client = boto3.client('s3')
> ```